# variable declaration problem inside struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I declared a Normal Structure In C:

```
typedef struct arr_struct{  

 int* original;  
 int size;        
 int first[size/2];  
 int second[size-(size/2)];  
};
```

when compile it gives me:

> test.c:11: error: ‘size’ undeclared here (not in a function)

any explanation?

Comment: I like `size-(size/2)` for odd sizes! :-)

Comment: what about (size+1)/2 ??

Comment: every one has his style :D but yours is more efficient you fetch size from the symbol table one time I fetch it twice. not bad :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error message because you're trying to use the `size` member of the struct illegally.  For one thing, the struct type definition isn't complete until the closing `}`, so until then the compiler doesn't know that there's a `size` member within the struct.  For another, you cannot refer to a struct member without a struct instance; when you used the expression `size` the declarators for `first` and `second`, the compiler was looking for a variable named `size` *outside* of the struct definition.

It *is* possible to use a VLA within a struct type, but that's really not the approach you want to take here if you're doing what I think you're doing.  Better to make `first` and `second` pointers to `int` and allocate them as necessary (as demonstrated by a couple of the answers above).

Answer (score 4):

You can't define arrays based on a variable size.  The size has to be known at compile time.  You'll need to make `first` and `second` pointers and dynamically allocate them once `size` is known.

Comment: Actually you can have arrays based on a variable size, but it appears that it doesn't apply inside a struct.

Comment: Yeah I remember something in C99 about variable size arrays.  But the last time I did any pure C (not C++) programming, I was on a non-compliant compiler so I never used them in practice.

Comment: You can only have an array of indeterminate size as the last member of a structure (flexible array member) in C99.  And since only one can be the last, you can only have one such flexible array member.  You also can't use them in arrays, or in other structures.

Comment: Guys, the error message has **nothing to do** with using a VLA in a struct and everything to do with trying to use the `size` member incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
int val;
scanf("%d",&val);
int a[val];
```

The above code actually compiles and runs in my gcc compiler.

The reason for not working inside a  struct could be due to the lining up of elements inside a struct whose size can't be determined at compile time. I am not fully sure about it though.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation and usage for what miked said could be (without error checking):

```
typedef struct
{
   int size;
   int* first;
   int* second;
} arr_struct;

// Prepare an arr_struct for use.
arr_struct foo;
foo.size = 1337;
foo.first = malloc(sizeof(int)*foo.size);
foo.second = malloc(sizeof(int)*(foo.size-foo.size/2));
```

Do remember to `free(foo.first)` and `free(foo.second)` when you're done, though!

Comment: i did this solution but I was asking for an explanation thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The size you provide for an array needs to be a constant expression. You have a couple of choices. One would be to include a couple of pointers, and allocate the space dynamically:

```
typedef struct {
    int* original;
    int size;
    int *first;
    int *second;
} arr_struct;
```

Another possibility would be to use only one array, and create a pointer to the proper point in it:

```
typedef struct { 
    int* original;
    int size;
    int *second;
    int first[];
} arr_struct;
```

This uses a flexible array member, which is new with C99 -- if you're using an out of date C compiler (e.g., MS VC++) it might not be supported directly<sup>1</sup>. In any case, this still requires dynamic allocation, but lets you do one large allocation for all the data instead of three separate allocations (one for the struct, and one each for `first` and `second`).

```
arr_struct *my_struct = malloc(sizeof(*my_struct) + size * sizeof(int));
my_struct->second = my_struct->first + size/2;
```

As an aside, note the syntax for `typedef` -- as it was, your `typedef` wasn't defining a name at all.

<sup>1</sup>The workaround is trivial though -- just define `first` with a size of 1 and subtract 1 from size in your allocation:

```
arr_struct *my_struct = malloc(sizeof(*my_struct) + (size-1) * sizeof(int));
```

In theory, this isn't required to work, but in fact it's just fine with all real compilers, at least AFAIK.

Comment: That's not a VLA, that's an *incomplete* array type.  There's a difference.

Comment: @John Bode: well, half right anyway. Thanks for drawing my attention to the slip -- I've edited in the correct term.